# Magento website getting some extra content in home page. How to remove that?

Tags: home, fatal-error

My website name is http://kopanaacreations.com/

In top of the website I am getting some code as " page content".
So how to remove this ?

Comment: This could be rendering from a number of different places. Have you tried going into your project folder and running `grep -ri 'page contents' ./` ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks that too much code coming from Google verification code example was pasted in Magento backend. I see following code in part of the page which displays Miscellaneous Scripts:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="MhgZldxDOmNWQ74FSWwNH3Ou7SfCHuTCq1N640thSUI" />
        <title> My title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        page contents
    </body>
</html>
```

Check backend `System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Miscellaneous Scripts` and remove mentioned code leaving only following line there:

`<meta name="google-site-verification" content="MhgZldxDOmNWQ74FSWwNH3Ou7SfCHuTCq1N640thSUI" />`

Comment: @Marius can we mark this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your html format is not correct, try viewing source of your homepage

Current format

```
<head>
  <meta />
  <title> My title </title>
</head>
<body>
page contents
</body>
</html>
{actual page content}

</html>
```

Try compare your base template with /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml

Also take a look at [New Title Tag and Meta Description Character Lengths](http://www.swellpath.com/2014/05/update-new-title-tag-meta-description-character-lengths/)